# Wrong position of absolute elements when browser zoom != 1?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a full screen div containing a map with absolutely positioned elements within it (cities, armies etc).

It all works fine with the default browser zoom, but if I change the browser zoom level, the positions change in seemingly random ways. Sometimes they're a pixel left/down/right/up with no rule I can figure out.

The absolute element positions are calculated based on their coordinates within the map, so for example if an element has coordinates `x: 5, y: 8` and one map quadrant has dimensions of `width=20px, height=20px`, then its position is calculated as:

```
var pos={
    "x": 5*20,
    "y": 8*20
};
```

My best guess is that the browser is rounding off these pixel values when the browser zoom is changed. For example, if `browser zoom==0.911` then the real quadrant size comes out to 18.22 x 18.22. If the browser rounds this value to 18.2 for example, then `pos` would be a few pixels off.

Is my assumption correct and is there a solution that will work consistently regardless of browser zoom level?

EDIT: one simple solution (that worked) was to structure the map as a table with fixed `td` width/height, but this creates an immense number of useless HTML nodes and slows down the load time of the page, which is unacceptable to the client. I need to keep the map as a simple div with just the absolutely positioned elements inside it.

Comment: Can you show your code in the `<head>` tag?

Comment: @PatrickMcDermott The <head> content is huge, with a lot of Javascript. I suppose you're interested in the metas? The only meta information we currently have is `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`.

Comment: Have you solved this? Also how you read `browser zoom` value?

Comment: This was never solved for me.